# Reload My html table with updated rows in teradata database

Tags: php, teradata

1. Totally I have 50 machines and created html table(webpage) with those machine names to reserve those free machines to user.
2. Once user want to reserve any machine, they want update the status column by marking "reserved" followed by user name and days.
3. I am updating those columns in teradata table.

Webpage created with html
connecting teradata using php.

Below is the my html and php code.

html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
    table {
        font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        font-family: calibri, serif;
        border: 1px solid Red;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <title>My Web-page</title>
    <body bgcolor="white">

    <h2>This is sample website which help you to find free machine</h2>

    <h2>List of machines</h2>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Machine Name</th>
        <th>Release</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Machine Owner</th>
        <th>Reserved By</th>
        <th>For Days</th>
        <th>Decision</th>
    </tr>
    <form id="select_co" name="select_co" method="post" action="check.php">
    <tr>
        <td>Machine 1</td>
        <td>15.10</td>
        <td>
            <select name="btname">
                <option value="Unreserved">Unreserved</option>
                <option value="Reserved">Reserved</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Rubesh</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  name="btname1" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="btname2">
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>   
        </td>
        <td> 
            <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
        </td> 
        </form>
    </tr>
    <form id="select_co" name="select_co" method="post" action="check.php">
    <tr>
        <td>Machine 2</td>
        <td>15.10</td>
        <td>
            <select name="btname">
                <option value="Unreserved">Unreserved</option>
                <option value="Reserved">Reserved</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Rubesh</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  name="btname1" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="btname2">
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>   
        </td>
        <td> 
            <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
        </td> 
        </form>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Php code :

```
<?php

    $btname = (isset($_POST['btname']) ? $_POST['btname'] : 'hi');
        echo $_POST['btname'];

    $btname1 = (isset($_POST['btname1']) ? $_POST['btname1'] : 'hi');
        echo $_POST['btname1'];

    $btname2    = (isset($_POST['btname2']) ? $_POST['btname2'] : 'there');
        echo $_POST['btname2'];

    if(isset($_POST['nw_update']))
    {
        echo("You clicked button one!");
        //and then execute a sql query here
        // establish connection
        $cn=odbc_connect('teradata','password','password');
        if (!$cn)
        {
            exit("Connection Failed: ".odbc_error().":".odbc_errormsg()."\n");
        }

        // populate employee table with sample data 
        if (!odbc_exec($cn, "INSERT INTO dr.t10 ('$btname', '$btname2', '$btname1')")) 
        {
            print("Execution failed - ".odbc_error().":".odbc_errormsg()."\n");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo" dhur";
    }
?>
```

My doubt is how do i reload my webpage with that updated one row changes?. I hope you will understand my problem. Please anyone help me to do same.

Thanks in advance.
Rubesh G.

Comment: So i am right that you want to reload your website everytime the data changes? Or: you want the change displayed in real-time, without to have to reload the page manually?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I trying same. Please share your ideas to get the same.

Comment: So with PHP this wont work. There are a few technologies. You can use Ajax if you want to stay with PHP and a bit of JS. Then, there is Websocket. Websocket would do what you want, but quite complicated to get into. May you just use a real-time framework? Like meteorjs or something... But you have to use javascript anyway.

Comment: okay thanks. Let me clarify me one thing, where we have to do reload concept in client or server side(means in html or php or some other).

Comment: Please let me help to do in ajax or java script. i am new to this areas. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any experience with javascript? Its not that easy to do a realtime-update. As i said, there are several technologies. With HTTP, only clients can do requests to the server. Websocket is another technologie that allows the server to push data to the client without a request. So data can be pushed whenever it changes. But to integrate websockets its not so easy. As i said, meteor would e a great framework. Quite simple and it comes with websocket, so everything is realtime by standard.